# Blackjack shows previous round on back

Tags: php

I'm trying to write a blackjack script, where you can bet x amount of "Bones", the sites premium currency, play a round of blackjack and then, in the end of you win, get twice the amount of "Bones" out.

I havent yet implented the Bones, but there is a major issue with my current script.
If the user is playing the game, hit the browsers back button, it shows the previous round.
This way, a user can for example click "Hit", see the next card he gets and if he Busts, hit the back button and click "Stand" instead.

http://pastebin.com/a4Ahxbaw

I hope i explained my problem properly, my English skills are not the greatest, and neither are my explanation skills. If there is any other information you would like, please request it, and i will do my best to make a deeper explanation.

Comment: You could save the state of the game, using your database store the values of the card(s) they have and use them values. That way if they click back the cards will still be the same as the stored values. After the game has finished (they win or lose) delete the row from the database and start again. This will also allow people to get halfway through a game and then come back to it later.

Comment: I’d use JavaScript for the front-end, mainly because PHP is a server-side language so it’s not going to be very interactive, and cache things, when using it to generate your Blackjack game.

Comment: I have considered JavaScript, how-ever my programming skills currently only include PHP, and minnor C#

Comment: @PeaceDealer Well, I know the way I said works because I used to use it. Probs not the best way but it does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save the state of the game, using your database store the values of the card(s) they have and use them values. That way if they click back the cards will still be the same as the stored values. After the game has finished (they win or lose) delete the row from the database and start again. This will also allow people to get halfway through a game and then come back to it later.

To expand on what I am saying:

New game -> user clicks "hit" -> insert row into database with card value 8H (8 of hearts)

User clicks "back" -> value of the card is still 8H as its now grabbing the value from the database.

```
if ( value in table for user) {
     use them values
} else {
     new value
}
```

User clicks "hit" again -> update the database with second card value 4C (4 Clubs) ->

User clicks "back" again but the value is still the same as before as again we grab from the database.

```
if ( value in table for user ) {
   use them values
} else {
   new value
}
```

If the user were to leave the page with the game not finished the all cards would remain there until the game is finished.

I hope this makes some sense and is possibly what you are looking for. I would agree with  Martin Bean tho, Javascript would be better for this.

Comment: Using the Database is a great idéa! Thanks!